# Material table default sorting does not work

Tags: angular

I have the following `mat-table`, but the sorting function is not working..

From what I can tell I have followed the instructions [here](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview) correctly, and it works fine in every way (arrow appears next to column header) except the data is not actually sorted.

**loans.component.html**

```
<div class="container">

  <h1>Current Loans</h1>

    <table mat-table [dataSource]="loans" class="mat-elevation-z8" matSort>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Id </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let loan">{{loan.id}}</td>
        </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="borrowerName">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Client Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let loan">{{loan.borrowerName}}</td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="fundingAmount">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Funding </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let loan">{{loan.fundingAmount}}</td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="repaymentAmount">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Repayment </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let loan">{{loan.repaymentAmount}}</td>
          </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let myRowData; columns: columnsToDisplay;"></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**loans.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Loan } from '../loan';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-loans',
  templateUrl: './loans.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./loans.component.css']
})
export class LoansComponent implements OnInit {

  loans: Loan[];
  columnsToDisplay = ['id', 'borrowerName', 'fundingAmount', 'repaymentAmount'];

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {

    this.getLoans().subscribe((loans) => {
      this.loans = loans;
      console.log(loans);
    })
  }

  getLoans() {
    return <Observable<Loan[]>> this.http.get('http://localhost:1113/api/loans');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

As per Sajeetharan's answer, I have now changed my component to

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Loan } from '../loan';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {MatTableDataSource, MatSort} from '@angular/material'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-loans',
  templateUrl: './loans.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./loans.component.css']
})
export class LoansComponent implements OnInit {
  columnsToDisplay = ['id', 'borrowerName', 'fundingAmount', 'repaymentAmount'];

  dataSource : MatTableDataSource<Loan>;

  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {

    this.getLoans().subscribe((loans) => {
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(loans);
      console.log(loans);
    });
  }

  getLoans() {
    return <Observable<Loan[]>> this.http.get('http://localhost:1113/api/loans');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
}
```

But I'm getting the same result...

The difference seems to be that in the sample they are displaying `const` data in the table, whereas I am retrieving it from an API - why would that make a difference?

**Attempt 3**

My code now looks like the below. I still can't sort and now I'm seeing

> Could not find Angular Material core theme. Most Material components may not work as expected. For more info refer to the theming guide: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Loan } from '../loan';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {MatTableDataSource, MatSort} from '@angular/material'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-loans',
  templateUrl: './loans.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./loans.component.css']
})
export class LoansComponent implements OnInit {
  columnsToDisplay = ['id', 'borrowerName', 'fundingAmount', 'repaymentAmount'];

  loans : Loan[];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.loans);

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {

    this.getLoans().subscribe((loans) => {
      this.loans = loans;
      // this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(loans);
    });
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.loans);

  }

  getLoans() {
    return <Observable<Loan[]>> this.http.get('http://localhost:1113/api/loans');
  }

  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  ngOnInit() {
    // this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() { 
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to convert loans to a mat datasource and use sort in your template to make it work.

I am sure, you have not done that anywhere in your .ts and template code .

you need to import,

**`import {MatTableDataSource, MatSort} from '@angular/material';`**

and then,

```
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA); //here pass loans
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
```

and in template,

```
  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
```

**[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ph5fak-4mljf5?file=app/table-sorting-example.html)**

Comment: Thank Sajeetharan. Unfortunately when I make this change, no data appears in my table. As you can see, I am not passing in constants to the table but rather getting the data from an API request. Do you know what I need to change get it working?

Comment: you need to call this as well in your code   ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

Comment: I tried adding that, but it still doesn't work and I can see `ERROR TypeError: "this.dataSource is undefined"` in the console.... which makes no sense

Comment: make sure you have defined it.

Comment: Please see my updated question - that is the code I used, and you can see the `dataSource` property definitely exists. I even trid initialising it at the property declaration and while this got rid of the error the sorting function still doesn't work

Comment: dataSource : MatTableDataSource<Loan>; should be  dataSource := new MatTableDataSource(loans) after you recieve your data from api;

Comment: by the time on ngOnint you dont have data so move the sort inside ngAfterviewInit not ngOninit

Comment: It doesn't work ... in addition I am now seeing `Could not find Angular Material core theme. Most Material components may not work as expected. For more info refer to the theming guide: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming` in the console... I think god might hate me

Answer (score 1):

Sajeetharan helped me find the answer.

Basically I did this:

```
ngAfterViewInit() { 
  this.getLoans().subscribe((loans) => {
    this.loans = loans;
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(loans);
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort; 
  });
}
```